# How would you notate that something is not in the domain of discourse?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic

For example, saying that something is specifically not in the domain of integers (not sure how to write the 'N' symbol).

Comment: Like $a\notin\Bbb N$?

Comment: To produce $\mathbb{N}$, type `$\mathbb{N}$`.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have realised I was being silly. I was thinking of something else and so I skipped over the fact that 'a∉N' is what I am looking for - I can't explain why, I am just silly.

Comment: It may be useful to remember that we can use something like $a \in \mathbb{Q}\backslash \mathbb{Z}$ if we want a non-integer rational number.

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally, the integers are denoted by $\mathbb{Z}$ which in Latex is written `$\mathbb{Z}$`. By enclosing Z in `\mathbb{}`, you are telling Latex to write Z in the math blackboard bold font, which is the standard font for sets of numbers. The natural numbers are denoted by $\mathbb{N}$, i.e. `$\mathbb{N}$`.

Mathematicians use an epsilon symbol to mean "is an element of." That is, $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ is read as "$x$ is an element of $\mathbb{Z}$." The Latex command for this epsilon is `\in`.

You want to say that something is *not* in the integers. To negate a statement, mathematicians often put a slash through a symbol. The statement $x \not\in \mathbb{Z}$ is read as "$x$ is not an element of $\mathbb{Z}$."  The Latex command for this is `$x \not\in \mathbb{Z}$`. In general, prefixing a symbol with '\not' in Latex will put a slash through it.